# What is NMAKE and how do I use it?

Tags: nmake

What is NMAKE and how do I use it?

Is there a good tutorial for NMAKE?

Comment: Why close? Is it a dupe?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[`NMAKE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd9y37ha.aspx) is Microsoft's implementation of the [`make`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)) tool.

Answer (score 1):

I want to add an updated answer for several threads asking this in 2023.

If you are using cmake on a windows machine without nmake you will likely encounter an error such as "'nmake' '-?'" or "CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set"

nmake is an executable file used by windows machines to execute a makefile

If you have a windows machine there are 2 options.

1. Use the nmake alternative mingw by adding this command to your script file "-G "MinGW Makefiles"" after "cmake -S . -B build"
2. Perform a web search for "visual studio build tools". Microsoft releases a command line build tools package as an alternative to the larger software downloads such as visual studio

The drawback of option 1 for me is that errors generate when using Gtest