# How to install nmake in windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, makefile

While I'm trying to run cmake on windows, I get the error that nmake cannot be found. It is to my understanding that nmake is the default build control software to use in windows but I haven't found any resources on how to download it and use it.

I am only interested in using vscode so I will prefer if I don't have to install Visual Studio.

Comment: You should not need nmake to build using mingw. With that said I am not familiar with the CMake Tools extension for VSCode.

Comment: What compiler do you want, MSVC or MinGW? Given that you don't want to install VS, I assume it's MinGW?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, I want to use MinGW

Comment: Then you don't want nmake. *"to my understanding that nmake is the default build control software to use in windows"* This only makes sense if you also want to use "the default compiler", aka MSVC, which comes with `nmake`.  CMake supports many different generators (nmake being one of them), pick something else. Either "MinGW Makefiles" (for `mingw32-make`) or "MSYS Makefiles" (for `make`). You can get both from https://www.msys2.org/, along with an up-to-date compiler.

Comment: [https://vector-of-bool.github.io/docs/vscode-cmake-tools/settings.html#cmake-generator](https://vector-of-bool.github.io/docs/vscode-cmake-tools/settings.html#cmake-generator)

Comment: see my comment at bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728873/what-is-nmake-and-how-do-i-use-it/77476751#77476751

Answer (score -2):

I found same issue in windows OS. I was able to resolve issue with following cmake command

cmake . -G "MinGw Makefiles"